# Extending MyViewController from another .storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

I try to create something like SDK - pack of default views, controllers wich developer can extends and customise

I have a problem with understanding how user can extends my UIViewController if his views didn't make programmatically, but created in separate .storyboard.

For UIView, we do something like this

```
-(id)init{

NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myXib" owner:self options:nil];
return [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];

}
```

How UIViewController can get own view from .storyboard?

I can't use .xib files becose my viewControllers have TableViews with dynamically TableViewCells.

UPD: 
I think it easy create UIViewController programmatically , add coupe views and all ChildViewControllers will have the same controls as his ParentViewController.
I want to add not programmatically this controls, but use .storyboard for this. And I can't imagine - how to bound this.

Comment: i guess you need to use storyboard reference...for this which is available in xcode 7

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyViewController * myVC = (MyViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerIdentifier"];
```

Comment: No, Igor! The keywords "Extends", "get own view". Your example make loop in my case. I look solution "takeViews" instead "instantiate".

Comment: ok, just use myVC.view . Or I still not understand what you mean?

Comment: ok, in this case you can try to override the  initWithCoder: method in your custom ViewController and initialize vc object from your storyboard. Than when your user will add ViewController on his storyboard  initWithCoder: will be called and your custom viewcontroller initialized from your storyboard will returned.

Answer (score 0):

The one who is using your library, can simply set the class of his ViewController to your ViewController from storyboard like :

[image]